# Is there any loss of information in converting jpg files to png?

Tags: deep-learning, png, jpeg

I am working on an image dataset using deep learning for segmentation. The training images and masks are in jpg format. I would like to know whether there is any loss of information in converting jpg to png? I searched a bit, but couldn't get any relevant information. I am trying out whether using png images improves segmentation accuracy. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG uses a lossless compression per default.

However, the PNG standard supports many different bit depths, color spaces and nifty features that can result in information loss. For example if you use a standard JPEG file with 24bit color and convert it to a PNG with 8bit color, you will lose image information.

When using default settings in libraries such as OpenCV or PIL, the conversion will be lossless though.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answer. I converted the images but found that it doesn't improve the segmentation model performance.

Comment: @sparkle Well, that's expected because those are exactly the same images. Just because you don't lose anything going from JPEG to PNG, doesn't mean you'll restore what was lost when saving something as JPEG in the first place.